# Avoid weak references by using function parameter types?

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting, retain-cycle

I have a function that accepts a block as a parameter. I can use trailing closures to pass in a block of code, but that closure must use a `weak` reference when retaining `self`.

For example, see the initializer of `MyClass2`:

```
class MyClass {
    func subscribe(using block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            block()
        }
    }
}

let test = MyClass()

class MyClass2 {

    var someProperty = 0

    init() {
        // Weakly referenced
        test.subscribe { [weak self] in
            self?.update()
        }
    }

    func update() {
        self.someProperty += 1
    }
}

MyClass2()
```

However, is this still needed if I pass in the closure as a function parameter like this?:

```
class MyClass2 {

    var someProperty = 0

    init() {
        // Avoid retain cycle?
        test.subscribe(using: update)
    }

    func update() {
        self.someProperty += 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The entire premise of your question ("but that closure must use a weak reference") is false. There was never any reason to use `weak self` in your first code. This would be perfectly reasonable:

```
init() {
    test.subscribe {
        self.update()
    }
}
```

The reason for needing to use `weak self` is that the closure referencing `self` is itself retained *by* `self`, causing a retain cycle; but that is not happening here.